# How can I tell EC2 to automatically reboot instances that have become CPU = 100% locked?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have asked this question before although the answer is no longer sufficient nor current. I would like to repost this question; how can this be achieved using Amazon's tools?

Comment: cant this be done using a small shell script ?

Comment: I think the answer to the old question is still valid: Fix the problem, not the symptoms. What has changed since then that you don't consider this a valid approach anymore?

Comment: @Sven, "Don't do it that way." is not a valid answer. It did not answer his question. There are numerous reasons why he may wish to choose a solution that elitists consider gauche. Perhaps he is required to work with a poor quality third party library. Perhaps he wants a temporary, quick and dirty solution to keep a system available over a weekend after the a-holes who built the system went out drinking on a Friday night. Perhaps he is inexperienced and needs to learn things the hard way... If we lived in a perfect word we wouldn't have the OOM Killer.

Comment: @NoahSpurrier: We have a *very* strong culture of "do it right or not at all" here, so, yes, "Don't do it this way" *is* a valid answer here, better live with it.  Also, I made a comment, asking for feedback to better understand the problem, and didn't answer the question. Lastly, I don't understand why you feel the urge to make such a comment on a four year old post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a tool from Amazon to do this but I would think that you could attack the problem in two ways:
A) find out what's causing the lockup and fix it

B) install watchdog software and have it reboot the system if a process is locked, assuming it is just a process and not the system becoming locked up

C) install/configure resource quotas to prevent user processes from bogging down the server resources.

If there were more information maybe others would have other suggestions, but from what you had posted I would think maybe these suggestions would be on the right track?